# In Ruby, how do you execute rspec code from a string rather than from a file?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to execute rspec code passed in to a Ruby process as a string. How can I execute rspec from within a Ruby process rather than from the commandline and capture the results?

```
# Ruby code    
code = '
#solution
class User
  def in_role?(role)
    true
  end  
end

#Tests to pass
describe User do
  it "should be in any roles assigned to it" do
    user = User.new
    user.should be_in_role("assigned role")
  end
end
'
# spec code
# numExamples = examples
# numFailures = failures
```

Comment: eval(code) appears to produce the results that "ruby myFile.rb" would produce. I'm looking for the eval() equivalent for "spec myFile.rb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you should get the code as a string in first place? If you want to have access to the data rspec produces, you can try using a [custom RSpec formatter](http://wiki.github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/custom-formatters)

Comment: I won't have access to a file system or commandline. I need to run spec from within Ruby code.